# Package hash downloaded by pipenv install differs from hash on pypi.org

Tags: python, pypi, pipenv

I am trying to install the package python-dateutil via pipenv. My Pipfile looks like this:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[[source]]
name = "testpypi"
url = "https://test.pypi.org/simple/"
verify_ssl = true

[packages]
python-dateutil = "==2.8.2"

[requires]
python_version = "3.10"
```

When running `pipenv install` I run into the following error:

```
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     python-dateutil==2.8.2 from https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/99/e2/8852a39753ff39d2d55f9823e7fe691c005b947423f30b7f6af67486fd2a/python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (from -r /tmp/pipenv-fx0nanjw-requirements/pipenv-gvgasxmt-hashed-reqs.txt (line 1)):
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected sha256 0123cacc1627ae19ddf3c27a5de5bd67ee4586fbdd6440d9748f8abb483d3e86
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or 961d03dc3453ebbc59dbdea9e4e11c5651520a876d0f4db161e8674aae935da9
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:              Got        1efd93a2e222eb7360b5396108fdfa04e9753637d24143b8026dfb48ffbc755b
```

I downloaded the files manually from pypi.org and pythonhosted.org and indeed: The file from pypi.org hashes to `961d03dc3453ebbc59dbdea9e4e11c5651520a876d0f4db161e8674aae935da9` and the one from pythonhosted.org to `1efd93a2e222eb7360b5396108fdfa04e9753637d24143b8026dfb48ffbc755b`.

The size of both files is identical. This is kind of strange - maybe some byte flipped when transferring to the mirror? Is there something I can do about it, i.e. force the package to be downloaded from pypi or can I only wait for this to resolve automatically? As it happens this problem also exists for other python packages (i.e. cmd2).